# Match a regular expression on words like '-aa', '_aa' and 'ab|ab'

Tags: regex, xml, xsd-validation

I am struggling to find a regexp to validate xml file using xsd schema for words like `-aa`, `_aa` and `ab|ab`. When I try an online [tool](https://regex101.com/) for matching regular expression the word `ab|ab` is matched 2 times, somehow the pipe | break the match.
My regexp:

```xml
      <xs:attribute name="element">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="(\w+\s*|'?\-*|\|)" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for the group with the pipe first, so it will only look for the second group if the first one does not match

```
(\w+\|\w+)|([-_a-z]+)
```

you can test this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/a7jsON/1)